# How to debug Google Tag manager with keycloak/oauth?

Tags: google-analytics, oauth, google-tag-manager

I have a dashboard written in Reactjs and it uses keycloak/oauth to authenticate users. Whenever I try to debug gtm with "preview" button, it looses the connection to debug when there is a redirect from keycloak after signin.

How to keep on debugging even when there is a redirect from the oauth?

I am using react-gtm-hook to implement gtm for react.